# Perl How to use array store input strings

Tags: arrays, perl

User first enter a number of lines. It then reads n lines of text from user input, and prints these lines backwards, i.e., if n=5, it prints the 5th
 line first, the 4th,  …, and the 1st,line last. I don't think wrong in my code, but when i start enter lines(line end with a newline), it won't stop. my array can store infinite number of lines which cause the problem stop them

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter number of n \n";
my $n = <STDIN>;
print "Enter couple lines of text \n";
my @array = (1..$n);
@array=<STDIN>;
do{
print "$array[$n]";
$n--;

}until($n=0);
```

Comment: Have you heard of the `chomp` function?

Answer (score 0):

The end loop condition is `do { … } until ($n = 0);`, which is equivalent to `do { … } while (!($n = 0));`

The trouble is that the condition is an assignment, and zero is always false, so the loop is infinite.

Use `do { … } until ($n == 0);`.

Note that the input is in the line `@array = <STDIN>;` — it reads all the input provided until EOF.  It is not constrained by the value of `$n` in any way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter number of n \n";
my $n = <STDIN>;
printf "Got %d\n", $n;

print "Enter couple lines of text \n";
my @array = (1..$n);
@array = <STDIN>;
do {
    print "$n = $array[$n]";
    $n--;
} until ($n == 0);
```

When run, that gives:

```
$ perl inf.pl
Enter number of n 
3
Got 3
Enter couple lines of text 
abc
def
ghi
jkl
^D
3 = jkl
2 = ghi
1 = def
$
```

I think your expectations are skewiff.

Comment: I changed it to ==,It's not working. The function is still infinite

Answer (score 0):

Below are some tips that might help you:

- Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of your scripts to enforce good coding practices and help you find syntax errors sooner.
- You must [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your input from `<STDIN>` to remove return characters.
- Use the array function [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) to add elements to the end of an array.  Other relevant array functions include [`pop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html), [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html), [`unshift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unshift.html), and potentially [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html).
- Use [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) to return an array of reversed order.
- Finally, the `for my $element (@array) {` can be a helpful construct for iterating over the elements of an array.

These tips lead to the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter number of n \n";
chomp(my $n = <STDIN>);

die "n must be an integer" if $n =~ /^\d+$/;

my @array;
print "Enter $n lines of text\n";
for (1..$n) {
    my $input = <STDIN>;
    # chomp $input; # Do you want line endings, or not?
    push @array, $input;
}

print "Here is your array: @array";
```

Comment: This works perfect, but i am wondering if i can use do until loop instead of using for loop

Comment: If you must, of course you can.  `do { .... } until @array == $n;`  The loop will continue until the number of elements in `@array` equals `$n`